# Deleted answer appears in search result

Tags: bug, deleted-answers, search

One day, I was doing some searches on Stack Overflow and found that one of the posts in the search result does not actually exist (perhaps it is a deleted post?). I added more search terms and was able to reduce the search result to only one entry.

Here's the query:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%22i+am+very+new+user+on+this%22

which contains only one result, which is an answer:
[Preview Image while file uploading using "UPLOADIFY"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565637/preview-image-while-file-uploading-using-uploadify/14525412#14525412)

but when I click on it, there is no such answer.

Additional findings:

- No such answer in [the timeline of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7565637/timeline) either.
- No such answer in [the user's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2011420/victor?tab=answers) either.
- On the right hand side of the question, it says "active   **1 month ago**", but all the posts/comments were over a year ago.
- Same behaviour no matter if I am logged in to stackoverflow.com or not while doing the search.
- No results found when [search by Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+%22i+am+very+new+user+on+this%22).
- Cannot find the post in the [StackExchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) (`SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE Id = 14525412`).
  However, I can find the question (`SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE Id = 7565637`)
  and the other answer (`SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE Id = 7869010`).
- Bug discovered 4 days ago (2013-03-17). I kept retrying in the following few days until today (2013-03-21), and it happened everyday, so this bug is not temporary.
- Oh, I just found out that it happens even if I [omit the "is:answer" search option](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22i+am+very+new+user+on+this%22).

Comment: Deleted answer?

Comment: A note for non-10k's: that answer was posted on January 25 and deleted by a moderator (probably due to flagging) the same day.

Comment: The StackExchange Data Explorer checks my privilege and therefore does not show me the deleted answer?

Comment: Probably some hiccup updating the search results cache. Editing the parent question caused it to be removed.

Comment: I'm getting zero results following those search links.  Weird random hiccup?

Comment: @blahdiblah - Looks like status-completed.