# Deleted answers showing up in search results; is this intended behavior?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, search

I decided to do some spring cleaning just now, and searched on Stack Overflow for [is:answer "having the same"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is:answer%20%22having%20the%20same%22) to see what came up.

Sorting by relevance, the first post is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766055/splitviewcontroller-master-disappears-in-landscape-ios/15229313#15229313) (10K-only, sorry) for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766055/splitviewcontroller-master-disappears-in-landscape-ios.

So I went to the answer to see if it needed to be flagged, and it's already been deleted!

**My question is:**  Can any user see deleted answers when searching this way, or only 10K'ers?  Is this by design, or is this a bug?

(The answers in [Deleted answer appears in search result](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172772/deleted-answer-appears-in-search-result?rq=1) seems to indicate it was a hiccup, but I can consistently reproduce this).

Comment: I don't have 10k rep and I can see the answer in the result list. But can't see it once on the post.

Comment: It appears in searches for anonymous users, even. Chrome -> File -> New Incognito Window -> paste search URL, deleted answer is first result.

Comment: Perhaps it's related to this bug that was recently posted on Programmers meta? [Search brings up deleted questions in results](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5694/1130)

Comment: Bad shards!  Bad!

Comment: I believe I have seen several posts just like that. They all have Thiefmaster and the delete date in common. And perhaps the glitch? :-)

Comment: @BoPersson - you might be right; [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044340/jquery-set-checkbox-checked/15612779#15612779) that I found from "please share" doesn't appear to show up on the search results anymore.